# Problem with mirroring (mirrored part is higher than the parent object and a middle object)

Tags: modeling, transforms

I mirrored my car front fender, now the outcome fender of the mirroring is higher than the car body and parent object of the mirroring process.

Left one is the original fender, on the right is my old fender and the new one I created by mirroring (is there a way to edit both objects like mirroring, but by not using the mirror modifier to create a new object?).

[image]

[image: Left one is the original fender, on right there is my old fender and a new one i created by mirroring]

[image]

Comment: I had a look at your blend file and can't see anything out of the ordinary. The mirrored mesh is at the same height as the original mesh, as it should be. Please explay better what you did, and what you expected to happen.

Comment: This is a closer picture about the problem: https://imgur.com/a/B1O0a

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3891" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3891/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use mirror modifier, you can create linked duplicate of your object. Select the fender mesh, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and click left. Now your duplicated object is at the same position as the original object. Now set the x-scale of your duplicate object to -1. Since the second object is not just duplicated, but *linked*, all mesh edits will show on both objects. This is also called an *instance*. You can make many instances of the same object.

Comment: What is the difference between alt+d and shift+d? Also for some reason <kbd> dosent work for me...

Comment: Shift+D creates a real duplicate, like a twin, where you can modify each mesh separately, while Alt+D creates an instance, like a mirror illusion - you can only modify the original mesh, and all other meshes will copy this.

Comment: <kbd> seems only to work in answers, not in comments.

Comment: Seems like i encountered a problem, whenvever i do ALT-D and s x-1 it, the mirror parent object comes also s x-1...

Answer (score 1):

Your bonnet is not horizontal, it is slightly tipped:

[image]

So, of course, if you mirror one fender, it's at a different height.

It would be best to delete one half of your mesh and use a mirror modifier. This way, you can avoid mistakes like this.

Comment: Seems to me like whole car chassis is slightly tipped? Even when i hide the bonnet the fender still dosent allign whit the car chassis....

Comment: Well, yeah, it seems so. As I told you: Just model one half of your mesh, and use a mirror modifier. Or for the tires, use the mirror with x- and y-axis, so you just have do model one tire.